# <__NSCFSet: 0x74957b0> was mutated while being enumerated

Tags: objective-c, memory-management

I can't undarstand why my code is crashes:

> <__NSCFSet: 0x74957b0> was mutated while being enumerated

Previously I read simular topics but their problem was that the code calls in different threads. My code always calls in Thread 1.

It crashes times to time.

Here is a code where it happens:

```
- (void)processReceivedResponse:(JTResponse *)aResponse {

    NSParameterAssert(aResponse);

    id <JTRequestDelegate> delegate = [self processResponseWithReceiver:aResponse];

    if (delegate == nil) {

        for (JTObserver *someObserver in observers) {

            if (someObserver.requestType == aResponse.type && 
                     ![someObserver.delegate isEqual:delegate]) {

                [someObserver.delegate didReceiveResponse:aResponse];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error you're getting is caused by something changing the "observers" set while you're looping through it.

It's hard to tell what that might be from just the snippet you posted. Is something in the delegate you're invoking on someObserver changing the "observers" set?

Comment: But how it is possible if I run the code in one thread? How it is possible to run different pieces of code in the same time in one thread? Where can I read about that in one post (not big guide)

Comment: It isn't about threads or running code "at te same time". You have a for-loop that is iterating over the elements in "observers". If any statement in that for-loop changes the contents of "observers" e.g. by adding an item or removing an item, you'll get this error.

Comment: Thank you for reply. I understand. But who can change it in the same time? Will @synchronize protect "observers" NSSet from changing in the same time?

Comment: You'll have to look at what's happening inside the someObserver.delegate that you're calling. @synchronize isn't going to help you because this is not a threading/concurrency issue. One way out of this is to do what rob mayoff suggests in his answer below - iterate over a copy of the array. That will make the error go away but you should really understand why the observers set is being changed and make sure that is correct. If not, you may be hiding a bug by just iterating over a copy.

Answer (score 3):

You could try simply copying the `observers` set and looping over the copy:

```
for (JTObserver *someObserver in [[observers copy] autorelease]) {
    ...
}
```

If you're using ARC (automatic reference counting), you don't need to use `autorelease`.